# Accessing SelectedItem from DDL within Repeater's ItemCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Hey all — I'm trying to access the SelectedItem value from a DropDown list that is housed within a Repeater, but I am receiving a Null Exception that is thrown. This repeater would iterate over upwards of 10 "products". Here is the code from my Web Form:

```
 <asp:repeater ID="rptProducts" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptProducts_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptProducts_ItemCommand">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 product">
                        <img src="<%# Eval("ImageFile") %>" class="col-xs-12" alt="<%# Eval("Name") %> Product Image"/>
                        <h3><%# Eval("Name") %></h3>
                        <p><%# Eval("ShortDescription") %></p>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" CommandName="click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>' UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                     </div>
                </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:repeater>
```

And the code from the .cs file where I'm trying to access DropDownList1's SelectedItem value.

```
protected void rptProducts_ItemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Repeater rpt = (Repeater)sender;
    DropDownList productDDL = (DropDownList)rpt.Items[0].FindControl("DropDownList1");
    int Qty = Convert.ToInt32(productDDL.SelectedItem.Text);

    Debug.WriteLine(rpt.ID);

    if (e.CommandName == "click")
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Clicked " + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "; Quantity: " + Qty);
    }

}
```

The Exception is being thrown at this line:

```
int Qty = Convert.ToInt32(productDDL.SelectedItem.Text);
```

I'm trying to prep that data to be pushed into a Session state, so I'm testing to ensure it is accessible. Is there something I'm missing and or a better way to access that specific value?

Comment: Where do you bind `DropDownList1` and `rptProducts` with data?

Comment: That was done in the ItemDataBound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `rptProducts_ItemCommand` event you are using fixed item index `0`, you need to select the item that fired item command

Below line of code will select the current triggered item.

```
DropDownList productDDL = (DropDownList)((RepeaterCommandEventArgs)e).Item.FindControl("DropDownList1");
```

Comment: That narrowed in and got me away from a Null Exception, but the SelectedItem is always the default option using that. I even tried placing it within an UpdatePanel to stop a full-page refresh

Comment: In my Page_Load, I wasn't checking for (!Page.IsPostBack), so your change along with that solved it. Thanks so much! Cheers :)